# BLE - last packets swallowed by iOS?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I'm communicating with the BLE sensor device with the custom GATT Profile from the iPhone app. At some point I command the sensor to give me stored data at the maximal rate. As the end of data, characteristic value of all 0xfffffff is used.

While this transfer generally works, sometimes the last value (and a couple of previous ones) is not reported to my app.

I was testing the same process from an Android phone and there nothing is lost, each time full data set is returned.

So it looks to me now as maybe iOS BT stack is overwhelmed and starts losing packets? Are there any similar experience in the community?

Comment: Assuming your sensor device is configured as "central device", then transmission speed is set by the client device (i.e. your iPhone), which selects a suitable transmission-rate (timeout values) based on what the central device is capable of. If the BLE stack on your phone cant keep up with the transmissions, it will negotiate a lower speed and try again, until the lowest speed supported by the sensor device is reached. If that doesnt work, you'll get timeout-errors. Since you're not getting errors from the stack, I would advise to look for the problem in your own code.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer. Do you have spontaneous ideas where to look for in my code? "didUpdateValueForCharacteristic" just not being called at the end of transmission. I do not see may options to do it differently